# Check if an item exists in dataprovider

Tags: apache-flex, dataprovider

Good afternoon.

I need to check if the item already exists before add in an dataprovider. But the indexOf method always return -1 wheen i try to do this check in my array. Anyone who can help me? Thank you.

```
var contacts:Array = new Array();

for each(var i:Object in windowAddContact.selectedContacts)  {

  if(contacts.indexOf(i) == -1) {

    contacts.push(i);               
  }
}

contactList.dataProvider = contacts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code; you've provided; I wouldn't expect indexOf to return anything but -1; unless youhave multiple instances of the same object in windowAddContact.selectedContacts; which is possible but seems unlikely.

The contacts array starts out empty and all this code does is copy items from a collection into an Array.  Try this:

```
var contacts:Array = new Array();
contacts.add(windowAddContact.selectedContacts[0]);
for each(var i:Object in windowAddContact.selectedContacts)  {

  if(contacts.indexOf(i) == -1) {

    contacts.push(i);               
  }
}
```

And I'll bet you'll see indexOf(i) return something other than -1 once.  I'm unclear what you're trying to do, though.  Why is the loop necessary?  Can't you just do:

```
contactList.dataProvider = windowAddContact.selectedContacts;
```

Comment: Thank you for help. I can not make this:

contactList.dataProvider = windowAddContact.selectedContacts;

because i need to check if the contacts already exists in my dataProvider before add. The indexOf method does not work with the array contacts. I do not know why. I'm trying to create a method for make this verification:

Comment: var contacts:Array = new Array();

    for each(var i:Object in windowAddContact.selectedContacts)  {

      if(contacts.indexOf(i) == -1) {

        contacts.push(i);               
      }
    }

    contactList.dataProvider = contacts;      

    public function toAdd(obj:Object):Boolean {
    
      for each(var i1:Object in contacts){
                  
  for(var i2:int = 0; i2 < obj.length; i2++){
            
     if(i1.idContact == obj.idContact) {       
     return false;
     }                 
  }         
       }    
          return true;        
       }

Comment: Sorry if i am being noob too much. I am new in development. I do not know why the ident do not work in this commentary.

Comment: Adding code to comments doesn't work very well.  IF my answer does not contain your solution; you shouldn't mark it as such.  If you have more code to share, you should edit your original question and add it as an update.  Based on the code you've shared; I still say that your 'contacts' array is empty and therefore indexOf() will always return -1.  Keep in mind that indexOf will compare object instantiations.  IF you have two separate objects with identical data Flex will not consider them identical.

Comment: Again i appreciate your help and chose your answer because it was helpful to create a solution that solved my problem. I managed to check the contacts to add in my dataProvider. I can guarantee that my array of contacts is not empty. Peopl I apologize for not being able to be clear with my question. Thank you.